# Overriding attributes in chef

Tags: ruby, tomcat, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have to modify the CATALINA OPTIONS of the linko cookbook. My problem is the attributes for catalina are set by a dependant cookbook (tomcat).

Here is the code that defines the catalina options in the dependant cookbook TOMCAT

```
 catalina_options   = Array.new
          catalina_options  << "-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"
          catalina_options  << "-Xms#{new_resource.jvm_min_size}"
          catalina_options  << "-Xmx#{new_resource.jvm_max_size}"
          catalina_options  << "-XX:PermSize=#{new_resource.jvm_permsize}"
          catalina_options  << "-XX:MaxPermSize=#{new_resource.jvm_max_permsize}"

    template "#{new_resource.home}/bin/setenv.sh" do
            cookbook "ypg_tomcat"
            source "setenv.sh.erb"
            owner new_resource.user
            group new_resource.group
            variables({
               :java_home         => "/usr/lib/jvm/default-java",
               :java_options      => "#{java_options.join(' ')} #{new_resource.java_options}",
               :catalina_options1 => "#{catalina_options.join(' ')}",
               :catalina_options2 => "#{new_resource.catalina_options}",
               :classpath         => new_resource.classpath,
               :catalina_home     => "#{node[:ypg_tomcat][:home]}",
               :gc_opts           => "#{java_options.join(' ')} #{new_resource.gc_opts}",
               :solr_opts         => new_resource.solr_opts,
               :dcosp_running_env => new_resource.dcosp_running_env
            })
            notifies :restart, "service[#{new_resource.service_name}]"
          end
```

So i tried setting an override in my linko cookbook as follow :
Content of the master.rb file :

```
if node[:yp_linko][:overwrite_gc]
  node.override['yp_linko']['catalina_options'] = node['yp_linko']['overwrite_gc']
end
```

And in my attribute file (default.rb) i added the parameters that i want :

```
default['yp_linko']['overwrite_gc'] = '-XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC'
```

Now when i run my teamcity project, i get the following parameters in my setenv.sh file for catalina :

```
CATALINA_OPTS="-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xms12G -Xmx16G -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+DEFAULTRBOVERWRITE -javaagent:/var/lib/newrelic/tomcat/newrelic.jar
```

So somehow it still keeps the default values and adds my own parameters at the end instead of over riding them.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I even went so far as to try adding a 

 "override_attributes": {
   "ypg_tomcat": {
     "catalina_options": "test1234"

into my json file but still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ypg_tomcat` cookbook is not public so we (outside of your company) have no way to know exactly what it is doing. But given that there is `catalina_options1` and `catalina_options2`, I'm guessing the concat is internal, probably something like `CATALINA_OPTS="<%= @catalina_options1 %> <%= @catalina_options2 %>"` inside the template file. In which case stuff in `2` will always just be appended and you can't specifically override the stuff in `1` because it isn't from the node attribute in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the answer
And yes it indeed concat in the template file with the following code :
`% if @dcosp_running_env and @dcosp_running_env != '' -%>

CATALINA_HOME=<%=@catalina_home%>
RUNNING_ENV=<%=@dcosp_running_env%>
LINKO_BASE=$RUNNING_ENV/solr_home
JAVA_OPTS="<%=@gc_opts%> <%=@solr_opts%>"
CATALINA_OPTS="<%=@catalina_options1%>"

<% else -%>

JAVA_OPTS="<%=@java_options%>"
CATALINA_OPTS="<%=@catalina_options1%> <%=@catalina_options2%>"`


So you're saying there's absolutely no way to overwrite the catalina_options1?

Comment: This made me think of an alternate solution, tell me what you think :
Adding a :postinstall that calls a little bash file that will overwrite the content of the config file after the build is done.

Comment: I mean you showed the code for it in your question, and as for how to fix it: you just fix the cookbook. You said "the tomcat cookbook" but the code shows it's some kind of local fork or wrapper specific to your company. So just fix the code to do what you want.